# function creating html table from python object

Tags: python, html, django

I'm writting a Django application. I have Python matrix object and after I finish the computations I do with Python I want to print the matrix to my HTML template.

The most convenient way seems to be to do this with Django's

```
{% for ... %}
{% endfor %}
```

This, however, isn't very practical for me. I simple want to put inside my template something like

```
print(matrix)
```

-is it possible to do this with Django? Some kind of an inline function?

Comment: You haven't stated what a "matrix object" is. But yes, if it has a method that prints it out, you can call that.

Comment: matrix object is an object with attribute 'rows', which is a list of lists. How can I make a method that prints it out?

Python object can't have a method that prints it to HTML can it?

Answer (score 0):

You could write your own custom template filter, however you should see if [`django-tables2`](https://django-tables2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/pages/tutorial.html) fits your requirements.

With `django-tables2` you can pass it a list of objects and it will take the attributes as rows.

Then in your `.html` template it's just a case of:

```
{% load render_table from django_tables2 %}
[...]
<body>
    {% render_table matrix %}
</body>
```